# bash: environment variable lost after su root?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, su

I defined some aliases in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.
When I login using `herbert`, I can use these aliases.
But after I `su root`, these aliases can't be used anymore.

This is very strange because `configs` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` should be global and can be used by all users.

Everything worked fine before but went strange these days. What I can remember is that I upgraded my Bash, from 4.2.25 to 4.3.30, but I am not sure whether this version change is the reason.

Is this due to Bash versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `su root` (or just `su`), the user ID is changed to that of the superuser but the default environment isn't loaded. Instead, try `su -`.

Paraphrasing the manual (`man su`), the option `-`, `-l` or `--login` provides a similar environment to what you would get if you logged in directly as that user. This means that things such as profiles will be loaded.

Comment: when I try "su -", it works perfectly as before. But I still wonder why "su root" works fine with bash 4.2.25. I have used these alias for a long time and problem arose only after I upgraded my bash

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. Without knowing more about your configuration, it's hard so say why the behaviour has changed between versions. Perhaps the suggestions provided in the other answer are relevant. Personally I would recommend always using `su -`, as this should work in all cases.

Comment: futhermore, when I use "su root", alias defined in /etc/bash.bashrc will lose effect while exported variables such as "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" can still take effect. That's quite weird!! Shouldn't alias and variables behave the same?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure :) Perhaps someone else will be able to shed some light on the issue but I think the solution is to always use the `-` switch. This question is quite borderline off-topic as it is (it would be better suited to Linux/Unix Stack Exchange in my opinion) so if you are looking for more details about *why*, perhaps it's worth asking a question there.

Comment: @Herbert Environment variables get inherited, aliases and functions and other stuff you put in `bashrc` does not. If your bash 4.3.30 is custom built, and doesn't source `/etc/bash.bashrc` while the OS provided one does, then that explains what you're seeing.

Comment: @geirha Last question is, why environment variables get inherited while alias and functions doesn't? They are both put in the /etc/bash.bashrc and when I login as "herbert", both alias and variables can work. But when I "su root", only variables can work. Why is that?

Comment: Fact is , when I use "su root", only variables can work but when I "su -", both alias and variables can work. I know the differences between "su root" and "su -", but I wonder why alias and variables are treated differently

Comment: @Herbert, the difference is that with `su root` you are starting an interactive **non**-login shell, which means only `~/.bashrc` gets read (and `/etc/bash.bashrc` if you configured bash that way). When you run `su -`, you start an interactive login shell, in which case only `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` are read. By convention, you in turn source bashrc from the profile files. In your case, `/etc/profile` likely sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` specifically, whereas for **non**-login shells, it only sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` if bash is configured to. Please see my answer.

Comment: @geirha Yes! The trick is, for my 4.2.25 bash, ~/.bashrc sources /etc/bash.bashrc while for my 4.3.30 bash, ~/.bashrc doesn't source /etc/bash.bashrc. But when I compared these 2 .bashrc files, I didn't see any config like "if [-f /etc/bash.bashrc] ; then . /etc/bash.bashrc" in either of them. Is there any other method that could force .bashrc to source /etc/bash.bashrc first??

Comment: @Herbert, like I explain in my answer. your bash-4.3.30 has been compiled with default configuration, while the bash-4.2.25 has been configured to specifically also source `/etc/bash.bashrc` in addition to `~/.bashrc` when started in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you built bash 4.3.30 yourself, you probably forgot to configure it the same way your OS configured it. Many Linux distributions modify bash to source a file like `/etc/bash.bashrc` in addition to `~/.bashrc` for interactive shells. Vanilla bash only sources `~/.bashrc`.

The configuration is done by modifying `config-top.h` if I remember correctly.

Also see [Dot Files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles).